# Problem adding unallocated space to Ubuntu partition

Tags: gparted, disk, resize, unallocated

i saw different threads here about increasing partition space but unfortunately i can't manage to resize my disk, neither the key sign that shows that the partition is mounted is present. I created a new ext4 format partition from the unallocated space and it can be resized according to the threads here, but my ubuntu partition won't do it. Would appreciate all the answers. ubuntu version is 20.04
everything i did was from the live-ubuntu mounted on usb.

[image: Disks screen]

Comment: Welcome to AU. Please provide more information ... eg what Ubuntu version, what your partitions look like at present. It's hard to offer any help with so little information.

Comment: First of all thanks for the welcome , i added partitions screen from the disks application but i'm not sure if that's enough, ubuntu version is 20.04.4. everything i did was from the live-ubuntu mounted on usb.

Comment: You have to boot into a live session to do this. Also sda6 has no unallocated space adjacent to it. You need to move  partition 7 to the end of the drive. That will move the unallocated space next to sda6

Comment: i did it in gparted using   try ubuntu from usb , i suppose you mean that by live session?also how can i move partition 7 ? i don't recall move/resize option giving me that choice

Comment: If NTFS better to use Windows tools. It may be hibernated or need chkdsk and then gparted or disks may not correctly handle it. I  prefer gparted for these types of changes to partitions.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for taking time to help guys, in my case the particular reason i couldn't manage to add unallocated space to ubuntu partition was that unallocated space and desired partition were not next to eachother. I solved it since the partition between them was totally empty and i had no data there so i deleted it, therefore ubuntu partition and unallocated space got next to each other. Hopefully someone will provide more useful and safe solution for others.

Comment: I think what you did was exactly right - and probably much safer than trying to move the partition.

Comment: Thanks, hopefully it will be useful for others having the same problem. Maybe i should mark this as solved?